# How can I switch from seonds to minutes to hour in jQuery Count Up

Tags: jquery

In the below I have a countup timer that hours, minutes and seconds, but I would like this to only show higher value that is not 0 and then append the respective naming, i.e.

- If count up is between 00:00:00 and 00:00:59 I would like it to show i.e : 49 seconds
- When between 00:01:00 and 00:59:59 I would like it to display i.e : 26 minutes
- When between 00:59:59 and 23:59:59 I would like it to display i.e : 13 hours

(If it is possible I would even like it to show days, but not necessary)

Is this even possible, and if so, how can I achieve this?

My initial script:

```js
function startCount() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".count").text(function() {
      var val = +$(this).data("secs");
      $(this).data("secs",++val);
      return new Date(val * 1000).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
    })
  }, 1000);
}
startCount()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="count" data-secs="89895"></div>
```

Comment: _"s this even possible"_ - Yes. _"and if so, how can I achive this?"_ - With math and `if`s

Comment: It feels worth pointing out if you "would even like it to show Days", JS interval isn't particularly reliable (when it comes to exact time), a 1000ms interval is **roughly** 1000ms so you will usually end up with compound errors if you leave it running for a significant amount of time.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas the math I was aware of, my problem is that this type of jQuery is way above my jQuery skills .. What I have tried is that I have googled to see If I somehow could find some documentation on how to format the output, given my initial script, and how it could be possible to swap the substring depending on the value, but until this point I have only found some old documentattion that I have not been able to work. I understand basic jQuery, but is still a newbie in jQuery.

Comment: good point @DBS, but I do not think that this will be an issue since the user might not be at the one page for more than max a couple of hours, and when they enter again it will be refreshed .. this is not for a 24/7 display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math problem, hope this is the desired output.

```js
function startCount() {
  $('.count').data('initial', new Date().getTime() - ($('.count').data('secs') || 0) * 1000);
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".count").text(function() {
      const diff = new Date().getTime() - $(this).data('initial');
      if (Math.floor(diff / (24 * 3600000)) > 0) {
          return Math.floor(diff / (24 * 3600000)) + 'd'; // more than 1 day
      } else if (Math.floor(diff / 3600000) > 0) {
          return Math.floor(diff / 3600000) + 'h'; // more than 1 hour
      } else if (Math.floor(diff / 60000) > 0) {
          return Math.floor(diff / 60000) + 'm'; // more than 1 minute
      } else {
          return Math.floor(diff / 1000) + 's';
      }
    })
  }, 1000);
}
startCount()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="count" data-secs="0"></div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much @ProGu !! That is deffinently what I was looking for! .. Thank you for your kind help :-)